# how to display label of react-select array in a text field

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to react and am trying to solve a problem.

I am trying to display the value of a drop down component in the next text field in react how do I do this?

This is my code:

The text box is showing object:

import Select from "react-select";

```
const customerCode = [
  { value: "1", label: "Hyundai" },
  { value: "2", label: "Maruti" },
  { value: "3", label: "Toyota" },
];

export class Sample1 extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      email: "",
      password: "",
      isEmpty: false,
      isEmpty1: false,
      isEmpty2: false,
      selectedOption: "",
      TDCOption: "",
      customercode: "",

      validate: {
        emailState: "",
      },
    };
  }

handleChangeCC = (customercode) => {
    this.setState({ customercode });

    console.log(`Option selected1:`, customercode);
  };

render() {
    const { selectedOption, TDCOption, customercode } = this.state;

    return (
      <Container fluid={true}>
        <Card className="card-box shadow mt--100">
          <div className="login-form">
            <Form className="form">
              <h1 className="text-center">
                <span className="font-weight-bold">
                  Special Vehicle Request
                </span>
              </h1>
              <h2 className="text-center">Welcome</h2>
              
              <Select
                className="select"
                isMulti
                id="CustomerCode"
                placeholder="Search Customer Code..."
                value={customercode}
                onChange={this.handleChangeCC}
                options={customerCode}
                styles={{
                  control: (provided, state) => ({
                    ...provided,
                    boxShadow: "none",
                    // borderBottom: "1px dotted pink",
                    borderBottom: this.state.isEmpty2
                      ? "1px solid red"
                      : "1px solid black",
                  }),
                }}
              />
              <FormGroup className="form-group">
                <Label>Customer Name</Label>

                <Input
                  type="code"
                  placeholder="Customer Name"
                  id="customername"
                  defaultValue={this.state.customercode}
                  style={{
                    borderBottomColor: this.state.isEmpty ? "red" : "black",
                    borderBottomWidth: 1,
                  }}
                />
              </FormGroup>
              
              <Button
                className="btn-sm btn-dark btn-block"
                style={{ width: "100%" }}
                onClick={this.validateEmail}
              >
                Log in
              </Button>
            </Form>
          </div>
        </Card>
      </Container>
    );
  }
}

export default Sample1;
```

How do I put the value or label of the dropdown in the text field value. Or How do I extract the value or label of a dropdownlist

Answer (score 0):

React-Select's `onChange` method returns the entire selected object

```js
(option, {action}) => {}
```

According to the documentation, `onChange` will be fired for a number of different `action`s

```js
ActionTypes = | 'clear' | 'create-option' | 'deselect-option' | 'pop-value' | 'remove-value' | 'select-option' | 'set-value'
```

So you will want to tailor your `onChange` according to the action. You have to account for the possibility that the `option` passed may be `undefined`.

```js
handleChangeCC = (option = {}) => {
    const newLabel = option.label
    this.setState(option);
    // set a state variable here for the 'value' of your input
    console.log(`Option selected1:`, customercode);
  };
```

The `defaultValue` is only good for the initial render of your component. You can't typically update it with state updates. (typically)

Comment: Hi Ran the code but it is not extracting any one value, how do I extract label or value

Comment: What does your new code look like?